# FIFO behavior for Array.pop in javascript?

Tags: javascript, arrays, fifo

I want an Array method similar to Array.pop() that exhibits First In First Out behavior, instead of the native FILO behavior. Is there an easy way to do so?

Imagine a javascript console:

```
>> array = [];
>> array.push(1);
>> array.push(2);
>> array.push(3);
>> array.fifopop();
1      <-- array.pop() yields 3, instead
```

Comment: use `array.shift()` .... or use `array.unshift()` instead of `array.push()` then keep using `array.pop()` ... shift/unshift works on array "top" ... push/pop works on array "bottom"

Comment: Aa shift() is expensive on large arrays, you may want to use the tiny [tiny-queue](https://www.npmjs.com/package/tiny-queue) library instead.

Answer (score 50, accepted):

You can use array.prototype.shift()

```
>> array = [];
>> array.push(1);
>> array.push(2);
>> array.push(3);
>> array.shift();  //outputs 1 and removes it from the array
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/shift

Answer (score 7):

The method is `array.shift()`. It pulls the first array element much as `array.pop()` pulls the last element.